# Vue Router bind router-link-active with function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

Im looking to run a function that corresponds with each router link with that has the default class 'router-link-active'.

For simplicity I would like to replicate basic CSS class/style change for each active link using Javascript or Vue.js Directives.

**[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JBWRyg)**

```
<router-link to="/1" class="link ROUTER-LINK-ACTIVE">one
<span style="change this within function when active"></span>
</router-link>
```

thank you for any insight )

Comment: are you want to call function on each route in vue-router??

Comment: no sorry . Only the link with the active class. Im probably trying to over simplify. I am using gsap animation that would need to be inside a function. I would like to apply this function to each specific  'active' router link.